# Which is the best approach to deploy MERN stack app on AMAZON EC2?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, mern

I am googling a lot to be sure the best approach to deploy MERN stack app on aws ec2 ... in some examples Nginx being used in server (expressjs) part and in some cases its being used for Recatjs part and the express js part is just hosted in node , React even can be hosted in s3 I guesss .. so what is the best approach however?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without configuring the server yourself in EC2, you can simply use managed Node.js hosting provided by AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

If you want to directly configure EC2 instance and deploy, you can follow this tutorial to do the deployment https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/18/react-nodejs-on-aws-how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-amazon-ec2